# Is it safe to drive 2 miles to garage with a broken coil spring?

Tags: ford, springs

The driverside coil spring on my ford fiesta has snapped, though it snapped very near to the end and the coil has dropped 1 coil down. Would it be safe to drive to the garage which is 2 miles away if I drive slow and carefully?

The exposed snapped section is facing the towards the inside of the car so not likely to puncture the tyre, though there is a slight rub of the metal part which has dropped, from the metal plate where it would normally sit, on the inside tyre wall when you steer.

Comment: Some drive for months with a broken coil, others have a tire shredded instantly... answer is who knows, you may be lucky...

Comment: You could ask the garage if they could come and get the car - or use your insurance tow coverage, if you have it.